# Using parser_args values to feed a for loop (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, argparse, iterable, command-line-arguments

I am trying to create a script that takes multiple command line arguments of the same type, and then feeds them into a for loop for processing, the below is what I have in my code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='XYZ')
parser.add_argument('[values]', nargs='+', help='A list of values')

u = parser.parse_args(['3crlV5QaiuUjRz5kWze', 'F9Xw0rggHZ_PLs62q'])

for values in u:
    ... # do a bunch of stuff for each "value"
```

I understand that the values stored in parse_args are a NAMESPACE, hence the error below when I run my code:

```
TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not iterable
```

Is there any way to turn them into a list object? so that I can pass them to my for loop, or is there any other approach I should be using? Just getting started with python, so apologies in advance if this is a noob question

Comment: What type of values do you want to iterate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate `u.values` (the argument name you specified in `add_argument` call) not `u` itself; To do that you need to rename `[values]` to `values`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='XYZ')
parser.add_argument('values', nargs='+', help='A list of values')
#                   ^^^^^^^^

u = parser.parse_args(['3crlV5QaiuUjRz5kWze', 'F9Xw0rggHZ_PLs62q'])

for value in u.values:
    #        ^^^^^^^^
    # do a bunch of stuff for each "value"
```

Comment: A note in case anybody else comes along this question, though the question is tagged python3.x (and mentions python3.6) this solution works in python2.7+

Answer (score 0):

The values from parsing are in a simple of object of class `argparse.namespace` (which can be customized - see the docs).

Usually you access those values by attribute name, e.g. `args.foo`.  For unusual names you many have to use `getattr(args, '[values]')`.

In the simple case argument values are a single string or number.  With `nargs` like '*' or '+', the values will be in a list.  With `append` action type you may even get lists within lists.

I encourage users to print the `args` namespace.

```
In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='XYZ')
   ...: parser.add_argument('[values]', nargs='+', help='A list of values')....
In [3]: args =parser.parse_args(['3crlV5QaiuUjRz5kWze', 'F9Xw0rggHZ_PLs62q'])

In [4]: print(args)
Namespace([values]=['3crlV5QaiuUjRz5kWze', 'F9Xw0rggHZ_PLs62q'])
```

With your 'dest' I have to use the `getattr` to fetch the list of strings from `args`.

```
In [5]: getattr(args,'[values]')
Out[5]: ['3crlV5QaiuUjRz5kWze', 'F9Xw0rggHZ_PLs62q']
```

`args` is a simple object, so you can add attributes or modify existing ones.  e.g.

```
In [6]: args.values = ['3crlV5QaiuUjRz5kWze', 'F9Xw0rggHZ_PLs62q']
In [7]: print(args)
Namespace([values]=['3crlV5QaiuUjRz5kWze', 'F9Xw0rggHZ_PLs62q'], 
    values=['3crlV5QaiuUjRz5kWze', 'F9Xw0rggHZ_PLs62q'])
```

If you are more familiar with dictionaries, you can use `vars()`:

```
In [9]: vars(args)['values']
Out[9]: ['3crlV5QaiuUjRz5kWze', 'F9Xw0rggHZ_PLs62q']
```

Play around with this sort of thing an interactive Python session.